# Fail to run graph that was refrozen again with smaller resolution via object detection api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I downloaded `faster_rcnn_inception_v2` from models zoo. Its input resolution is `1024x600`. I tried to "refreeze" it with smaller resolution by changing the config from -

```
keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
  min_dimension: 600
  max_dimension: 1024
}
```

to

```
keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
  min_dimension: 360
  max_dimension: 640
}
```

And running the following command line -

```
python object_detection/export_inference_graph.py \
--pipeline_config_path /hdd/motorola/motorola_data/pre_trained/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline_small.config \
--trained_checkpoint_prefix /hdd/motorola/motorola_data/pre_trained/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt \
--output_directory /hdd/motorola/motorola_data/pre_trained/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28_small_reso/
```

Though when i run the graph on some input, i get the following error -

```
ValueError: NodeDef mentions attr 'explicit_paddings' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]; attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]>; NodeDef: {{node FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/separable_conv2d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/separable_conv2d/depthwise, FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/pointwise_weights/read). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
```

Is this the right way to resize input resolution of a graph without re-training it with the desired resolution?

Comment: Are you able to resolve this error? I too got the same error